# Are continuous product projections always split?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, fiber-bundles

Are continuous product projections always split? What's an example of a product projection without a continuous right inverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what you mean by "product projection", so I will give two examples.

The [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) says that the natural projection $TS^2 \mapsto S^2$ does not split.

On the other hand, for any nonempty topological spaces $X,Y$, the projection map $p_Y : X \times Y \to Y$ defined by $p_Y(x,y)=y$ always splits: pick $x_0 \in X$, and define $f(y)=(x_0,y)$.